# Get iptables rule from ufw

Tags: domain-name-system, ufw

Using ufw, concerning mDNS, I see:

```
~> sudo ufw enable
~> sudo iptables -L
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             mdns.mcast.net       udp dpt:mdns
```

My understanding is that this rule accepts all incoming IPs.

How to get the corresponding iptables rule, and, limit mDNS connections to local LAN (192.168.XXX.YYY) only?

Answer (score 1):

If you use ufw, I won't start touching iptables right away.

- First list your ufw rules using `ufw status numbered`
- Then delete the mdns rules `ufw del number`
- Then add the mdns rule again with the limit `ufw allow mdns in from 192.168.0.1/24`